# Real Time Core Image Filtering in iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-image

In its documentation, Apple says the following about real time filtering with CoreImage:

If your app supports real-time image processing you should create a CIContext object from an EAGL context rather than usingcontextWithOptions: and specifying the GPU. The advantage is that the rendered image stays on the GPU and never gets copied back to CPU memory. First you need to create an EAGL context:

I was able to accomplish this in iOS6 / iPhone5 using the following implementation:

```
self.eaglContext = [[[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2] autorelease];
self.ciContext = [[CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:_eaglContext options:[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNull null], kCIContextWorkingColorSpace, nil] autorelease]] autorelease];
self.filteredImage = [[CIImage imageWithCGImage:_image.CGImage] autorelease];

    GLKView *glkView = [[GLKView alloc] initWithFrame:self.imageView.bounds context:self.eaglContext];
    self.glkView = glkView;
    [self.glkView bindDrawable];
    [self.mainView addSubview:self.glkView];
    [glkView release];

    CGRect filterViewBounds = CGRectZero;
    filterViewBounds.size.width = self.glkView.drawableWidth;
    filterViewBounds.size.height = self.glkView.drawableHeight;
    self.filterViewBounds = filterViewBounds;

    [self.context drawImage:self.filteredImage inRect:self.filterViewBounds fromRect:[self.filteredImage extent]];
    [self.glkView display];
```

Then apply the filters as following:

```
CIImage *filteredImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:self.image.CGImage options:nil];

for (Filter *filter in self.filters)
{
    if ([filter apply])
    {
        [filter.filter setValue:filteredImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
        [filteredImage release];
        filteredImage = [[filter.filter outputImage] retain];
    }
}

    [self.glkView bindDrawable];
    [self.ciContext drawImage:filteredImage inRect:self.filterViewBounds fromRect:[filteredImage extent]];
    [self.glkView display];
```

However, on iOS5 / iPhone4 when I go to apply a filter I get:

```
CoreImage: EAGLContext framebuffer or renderbuffer incorrectly configured!
```

Filtering does work after this, however the performance is still very bad and almost similar to if I was saving the filtered image back to the CPU. Also is the fact that when I exit this particular view controller, then try to come back to it, it crashes.

Anyone can provide any help on this?